# Google Sheet: Transform a row of cells to a matrix of cells

Tags: google-sheets

Just wonder if there is a single (perhaps complex) formula that transforms a row of cells into a matrix of cells (defined by width)?

I suppose I can do it with App Script however I think a single formula would be a more elegant answer. Hope it can be done by simple combo of google sheets built-in formula.

[image]

Comment: is this for calendar where you store months in a row?

Comment: Yes it was the original objective. I could do it with other more clumsy formulas. But now it has become a more general interest topic to generate a matrix if data were not nice and flush equal to width x height.

It would be interesting, however, if there is a built-in calendar generating function too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, it takes the number of rows and columns you choose to make that array (r & c) to map through INDEX that row

```
=MAKEARRAY(4,4,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(1:1,(r-1)*4+c)))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! 
If the number of cell is not nice and flush matching the number of columns, the formula will create #NUM error for missing data to fill the matrix.  The solution is to apply an iferror() wrapper:
=iferror(MAKEARRAY(4,4,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(1:1,(r-1)*4+c))),)

The "4" within the lambda is hardcoded to match the second parameter "4" in the makearray() otherwise it would not work. Is there anyway to make it generic?

Comment: You could refer to cell values for each dimension: =MAKEARRAY(A2,B2,LAMBDA(r,c,IFERROR(INDEX(1:1,(r-1)*B2+c))))

Comment: Or wrap it in LAMBDA and change those finals 4,4 to your desired values: =LAMBDA(numro,numco,MAKEARRAY(numro,numco,LAMBDA(r,c,IFERROR(INDEX(1:1,(r-1)*numco+c)))))(4,4)

Comment: I was inspired by your formula and was playing with an additional LAMBDA() wrapping around your formula. You come up with the same solution! Excellent! Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful and you could go further!

Comment: Based on your formula, I added some date related formula to create a monthly calendar for the month in the date value within A2. It assume a Sun-Mon-...Sat layout and a 6row x 7column.

`=lambda(h, w, makearray(h, w, lambda(r, c, iferror(index({transpose(split(rept("|",mod(weekday(A2,2),7))&join("|",arrayformula(lambda(fd,nd,fd-1+sequence(nd))(int(A2),(date(year(A2),month(A2)+1,1)-date(year(A2),month(A2),1))))),"|",true,false))},(r-1)*w+c)))))(6,7)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do this.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(width,IFNA(HLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(CEILING(COLUMNS(B1:P1)/width),width),{SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(B1:P1));B1:P1},2,0)))(5))
```

It essentially creates a lookup table with the values in B1:P1 and their position and it uses that information to fill a nxm grid.

See [WRAPROWS in Google Sheets](https://ztiaa.com/posts/wraprows-in-google-sheets) to learn more about how it works.